# Unable to run solaris binary on solaris10

Tags: mongodb, solaris-10

I am running solaris 10.
I downloaded the 2.4.1 driver from mongodb.org

Here are the logs:

```
foo $ ./mongod --dbpath /dpool/mongodb/data  --pidfilepath /dpool/mongodb/run/mongod.pid
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.832 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=25116 port=27017        dbpath=/dpool/mongodb/data 64-bit host=foo.example.net
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten]
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: your operating system version does not support the method that MongoDB
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten] **       uses to detect impending page faults.
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten] **       This may result in slower performance for certain use cases
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten]
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.1
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten] git version: 1560959e9ce11a693be8b4d0d160d633eee75110
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten] build info: SunOS bs-smartos-x86-64-1.10gen.cc 5.11 joyent_20120424T232010Z i86pc BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Wed Apr 10 21:19:54.833 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/dpool/mongodb/data", pidfilepath: "/dpool/mongodb/run/mongod.pid" }
Segmentation Fault
foo $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/mongodb/lib
foo $ ls -lt /usr/local/mongodb/lib
total 6152
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mongo      255312 Oct 26  2009 libgcc_s.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mongo     5900688 Oct 26  2009 libstdc++.so.6
```

Any ideas? I used to run version 2.0.3 with no issues....

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB 2.4.1 build is currently done on SmartOS (which is based on OpenSolaris/Solaris 11), and there are some known issues on Solaris 10.

Your problem may be related to [SERVER-7404](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7404) in the MongoDB Jira but there could be other issues.

One of the community suggestions on SERVER-7404 may be useful:

> After downloading and installing libstdc++6-4.7.2\,REV\=2013.03.28-SunOS5.10-i386-CSW.pkg from opencsw it starts as usual

If you do get this working it would be helpful to comment on the Jira issue so other users know the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This binary looks like to have been tuned for a SunOS 5.11 kernel. You might want to try it under either Solaris 11 or an Illumos based OS to avoid this warning message.